# iOS: Uknown type name 'namespace'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS app which uses a custom GL View that I've subclassed. I need to replace the type of a variable declared in an existing .h file to this new class. However, I'm getting an error about the original parent class when compiling, "Unknown type name, 'namespace'" because of a namespace declaration.

On the face of it, my issue seems similar to this:
[Unknown type name 'namespace' in xCode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975239/unknown-type-name-namespace-in-xcode-4-2)

but my issue is that my variable is in the foo.h file and while the foo.mm file is set to Objective-C++, no matter what I set the .h file to, I keep getting the error. Any ideas on how I can address this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an 'answer' per se, but the reason this was failing was my own stupidity. I forgot multiple .m files were including the .h I was altering. Changing how those .m files get considered in XCode to Obj-C++ worked.